# MicroService Size Issue

Tags: deployment, microservices, size

I have a Project with about 85 micro service functions. The problem that I am facing is that due to 85 individual services the total deployment size goes up to around 7 gb with having individual WAR's of about 100 mb for each service.

Is there a way in which the size of each of the war files can be reduced?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the technology stack - both in terms of development and deployment? Could you add a list of JARs included into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of a WAR? Please include the sizes in the list.